# Avoid waiting on Servlet streams

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous

My Servler spends quite some time in reading `request.getInputStream()` and writing to `response.getOutputStream()`. In the long run, this can be a problem as its blocking a thread for nothing but reading/writing *literally* a few bytes per second. (*)

I'm never interested in a partial request data, the processing should not start before the request is completely available. Similarly for the response.

I guess, asynchronous IO would solve it, but I wonder what's the proper way. Maybe a servlet `Filter` replacing the `ServletInputStream` by a wrapped `ByteArrayInputStream`, using `request.startAsync` and calling the chained servlet after having collected the whole input?

- Is there already such a filter?
- Should I write one or should I use a different approach?

---

Note that what I mean is to avoid *wasting threads on slow servlet streams*. This isn't the same as `startAsync` which avoids *wasting threads just waiting for some event*.

And yes, at the moment it'd be a premature optimization.

#### My read loop as requested

There's nothing interesting in my current input stream reading method, but here you are:

```
private byte[] getInputBytes() throws IOException {
    ServletInputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
    final int len = request.getContentLength();
    if (len >= 0) {
        final byte[] result = new byte[len];
        ByteStreams.readFully(inputStream, result);
        return result;
    } else {
        return ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);
    }
}
```

That's all and it blocks when data aren't available; `ByteStreams` come from Guava.

#### Summary of my understanding so far

As the answers clearly state, it's impossible to work with servlet streams without wasting a thread on them. Neither the servlet architecture nor the common implementation expose anything allowing to say "buffer the whole data and call me only when you collected everything", albeit they use NIO and could do it.

The reason may be that usually a reverse proxy like nginx gets used, which can do it. nginx does this buffering by default and it couldn't be even switched off until [two years ago](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/251).

## Actually a supported case???

Given that many negative answer, I'm not sure, but it looks like my goal

> to avoid wasting threads on slow servlet streams

is actually *fully supported*: Since 3.1, there's [ServletInputStream.html#setReadListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletInputStream.html#setReadListener-javax.servlet.ReadListener-) which seems to be meant exactly for this. The thread allocated for processing `Servlet#Service` initially calls `request.startAsync()`, attaches the listener and gets returned to the pool by simply returning from `service`. The listener implements `onDataAvailable()`, which gets called when it's possible to read *without blocking*, adds a piece of data and returns. In `onAllDataRead()`, I can do the whole processing of the collected data.

There's an [example](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-bench/blob/master/bench-9-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/benchmark/Servlet31AsyncIOEchoBenchmark.java#L123), how it can be done with Jetty. It seems to cover non-blocking output as well.

---

(*) In the logfiles, I can see requests taking up to eight seconds which get spend on reading the input (100 bytes header + 100 bytes data). Such cases are rare, but they do happen, although the server is mostly idle. So I guess, it's a mobile client on a very bad connection (some users of ours connect from places having such bad connectivity).

Comment: Servlet 3.0 already provides an async API for Servlets. You don't have to roll your own.

Comment: @EJP Yes, but servlet async API is about freeing the thread when waiting on something. Here, I mean async IO, i.e., not wasting a thread when reading a slow stream (which happens to be a servlet stream). An implementation will use both ways as asynchronicity.

Comment: I would profile it and figure out what it's actually waiting for in the api, shouldn't take that long to read/write a few bytes... Your problem *likely* has nothing to do with running async vs old style io

Comment: @Kin My problem is currently rather minor as I it happens rarely (so it's not really bad for the server) and so far nobody complains. The slowness does not happen in my code as the very first and the very last thing I do is logging. It's not the GC as it gets logged and never takes more that a few milliseconds. It's not waiting for a connection or a thread as the server was pretty idle at this time. I'll surely investigate further, but I'm also really curious **how to do the asynchronous IO - I'd like to know it whether I use it or not**.

Comment: I don't really understand why your question has a bounty attached? If you want to learn how to write an nio web server, do that and test it out... Lots of examples and code already out there, just google "java nio web server"... Async io wouldn't solve the fact that you have to wait for tcp driver to marshal packets to bytes before your java classes can read them? If I'm wrong, what am I missing?

Comment: @Kin I've googled and found some pages I couldn't make much sense of. I guess, I could write an async nio web server, but I'm highly confused concerning servlets. IIRC Jetty (which I'm using) can do it out of the box, I just can't find the right article again (I always get `request.startAsync` related asynchronicity instead). Nothing can solve the problem of my code having to wait for the data, but eliminating a thread wasted on it would make me happy.

Comment: Jetty is open source, right? Get the code for the jetty server, attach a debugger to your jvm with the source code from jetty and debug... That will tell you exactly how getInputStream is implemented, can't think of a better way to answer your own question.

Comment: Show us your read/write loop code.

Comment: @Kin I have already debug it, but 1. it's complicated, 2. knowing how `org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput` is implemented would surely help if I was to re-implement it, but that's no my plan and 3. there's quite a lot of private members, so I'd have to fork it. Maybe I was too naive expecting that I could simply configure it like saying "don't call me until all data is available" or alike.

Comment: @ThomasRS Am I right assuming you want to see if I'm doing something wrong? I've added the code, but it's trivial. Concerning async, I haven't yet started with it (and I can't see how to do it given that the starting point is an input stream rather than an `AsynchronousSocketChannel`).

Comment: Ok, after reading EJPs asnwer i think i get what you're trying to do. Here's how I would go about it: you can probably solve for 1 using aspectj... add a pointcut to intercept the method call when container allocates a thread, form there you can join the allocated thread to another "asynch" thread or manager that you control and manage your async process from there, with a asyncserversocket or whatever method of comm u need between appl and the thread handling async callback.

Comment: In real life just use nginx in front before servlet engine.
see: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166284/does-nginx-also-buffer-http-request-from-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166284/does-nginx-also-buffer-http-request-from-client)

Answer (score 13):

[`HttpServletRequest#startAsync()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#startAsync--) isn't useful for this. That's only useful for push things like web sockets and the good 'ol SSE. Moreover, JSR356 Web Socket API is built on top of it.

Your concrete problem is understood, but this definitely can't be solved from the servlet on. You'd only end up wasting yet more threads for the very simple reason because the container has already dedicated the current thread to the servlet request until the request body is read fully up to the last bit, even if it's ultimately read by a newly spawned async thread.

To save threads, you actually need a servletcontainer which supports NIO and if necessary turn on that feature. With NIO, a single thread can handle as many TCP connections as the available heap memory allows it, instead of that a single thread is allocated per TCP connection. Then, in your servlet you don't at all need to worry about this delicate I/O task.

Almost all modern servletcontainers support it: [Undertow](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow) (WildFly), [Grizzly](https://github.com/javaee/grizzly) (GlassFish/Payara), [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org), [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), etc. Some have it by default enabled, others require extra configuration. Just refer their documentation using the keyword "NIO".

If you'd actually also want to save the servlet request thread itself, then you'd basically need to go a step back, drop servlets and implement a custom NIO based service on top of an existing NIO connector (Undertow, Grizzly, Jetty, etc).

Comment: IIUIC my Jetty already uses NIO in order to allocate thread per request instead of thread per connection. So I could imagine it could be told to wait for the whole response before allocating the thread instead of waiting for the first byte only.

Comment: You have to write the asyncreqprocessor for this yourself, but it's easier than it sounds? At least in my mind it is, concrete implementation not sure whether there would be any gain, it's possible there would be, it just depends on so many other factors... Anyway interesting experimental exercise, most def

Comment: *"in order to allocate thread per request instead of thread per connection"* that's not the point of NIO. Without NIO, you'd waste at least 2 threads in order to process this slow request. One for TCP and one for servlet. With NIO, you'll "waste" only one thread in order to process this slow request (that one for servlet; the one for TCP can be reused for other connections/requests). But you ultimately need at least one available thread anyway. How else would you process the request body in a threadsafe manner?

Comment: Exactly, you need a thread to process those SLOW requests, that thread can be managed separately in an async manner outside the blocking container, performance will come down to how many cores and how your os will juggle the scheduling... very experimental because no way to tell how will behave under heavy load, could even slow things down, so still need timeouts, etc... Like I said above lots of factors to consider

Comment: @Kin: as answered, that's not possible as per Servlet API. You'd only end up wasting yet more threads for the very simple reason because the container has already dedicated the current thread to the servlet request until the request body is read fully up to the last bit, even if it's ultimately read by a newly spawned async thread. You'd basically need to go a step back, drop servlets and implement a custom service on top of an existing NIO connector (Undertow, Grizzly, Jetty, etc).

Comment: *"in order to allocate thread per request instead of thread per connection = that's not the point of NIO"* I don't understand this. Forget slow requests, imagine an idle server with thousands of open connections and not so many threads. Without NIO, I could only poll all the `InputStream`s in a loop and hope for `available` not lying. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Without NIO, you can't keep a TCP socket open while the very same thread does different things. So it already stops there.

Answer (score 6):

1. You can't. The Servlet container allocates the thread to the request, and that's the end of it, it's allocated. That's the model. If you don't like that, you will have to stop using Servlets.
2. Even if you could solve (1), you can't start async I/O on an input stream.
3. The way to handle slow requests is to time them out, by setting the appropriate setting for whatever container you're using ... *if* you actually have a problem, and it's far from clear that you really do, with a mostly idle server and this only happening rarely.
4. Your read loop makes a distinction without a difference. Just read the request input stream to its end. The servlet container already ensures that end of stream happens at the content-length if provided.

Comment: Number 2 maybe a misnomer? Not saying for certain, because this is theoretical stuff, but my gut feeling is you should be able ot abstract and delegate to an async process.

Comment: @Kin Async IO !== Async process. OP just needs a web/servlet container supporting NIO. This can't be controlled from the servlet on.

Comment: why not? from what i understand, op wants to delegate the method that's actually doing the reading of bytes to run async in another thread, whose main feature is that it's not being used by the container... the thread allocated by the container that received original request would "complete" and a serversocketchannel would receive the original request and either call doGet or doPost or whatever other method in the api... Explain to me please why this behavior cannot be controlled? It doesn't even have to be hacky, this could live as a perfectly valid module or a feature of the container

Comment: @Kin 1. There is no 'misnomer' here, not that that's the correct word. You can't start asynchronous I/O from a Java input stream. There is no API for it. 2. The OP doesn't have access to the method that's doing the reading. It is hidden behind the facade of an `HttpServletRequestInputStream`, and, for the third time, you can't start asynchronous I/O from a Java input stream. 3. `ServerSocketChannels` don't receive anything except inbound connection requests, and if you mean `SocketChannels`, they are not asynchronous, and they are not even non-blocking if they are obtained from `Sockets`.

Comment: you can't start async io from an input stream, but you can start async io and PASS it an input stream for processing, when input stream completes, you can make async io complete the request... is that really so hard to figure out? also misnomer is absolutely the correct word to use, but i am not going to argue with you about it... See BalusC comment on his answer below, talking about the exact same thing

Comment: @Kin: Not possible as long as you're dealing with a servlet request. See my comment on your comment. That said, I'm not really interested in continuing this discussion before you carefully read up the servlet spec. It's just not possible. Period.

Comment: Timing out slow requests makes no sense when they're done by ordinary customers (as was the case). Currently are slow requests no problem, I mainly wanted to know if there's a solution in case they'll become a problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's a class called `org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter`, which is the class that receives the marshaled request from TCP worker thread. It has a method called "service" which does the bulk of the heavy lifting. This method is called by another class: `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor` which also has a method of the same name.

I find it interesting that I see so many hooks in the code to handle async io, which makes me wonder if this is not a built in feature of the container already? Anyway, with my limited knowledge, the best way that I can think of to implement the feature you are talking about, would be to create a class:

`public class MyAsyncReqHandlingAdapter extends CoyoteAdapter` and `@Override service()` method and roll your own... I don't have the time to devote to doing this now, but I may revisit in the future.

In this method you would need a way to identify *slow* requests and handle them, by handing them off to a single threaded nio processor and "complete" the request at that level, which, given the source code:

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/075920d486ca37e0286586a9f017b4159ac63d65/java/org/apache/coyote/http11/Http11Processor.java

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/3361b1321201431e65d59d168254cff4f8f8dc55/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/CoyoteAdapter.java

You should be able to figure out how to do. Interesting question and yes it can be done. Nothing I see in the spec says that it cannot...

Comment: This is for tomcat, obviously, but you should be able to derive the same info from any open source container...